# Generate colors for graph based on non-binned values of a vector

Tags: r, linear-gradients

I would like to generate colors for an xy graph based on a third variable. However, I do not want to use colorRampPalette or similar methods, because they all create ramps that are "predetermined". That is, between two extremes, one then chooses the number of colors and then the function "evenly" distributes along the ramp. To give the illusion of continuity, one has to bin the data and hope that one has guessed a number of colors that ends up not giving too wonky an outcome. That's not what I want. What I want is to do either of the following:

```
valuea {arbitrary} = colora
valuez {arbitrary} = colorz
```

Distribute colors according to the values of a vector along a color gradient without predefining the number of colors in the gradient between colora and colorz and placed according to the values of the vector.

```
valuea {min(vector)} = colora
valuea {max(vector)} = colorz
```

Do as above.

There is mention of a "colourschemes" package, but I'm in a windows machine that doesn't do tarballs, the windows version on that page goes to a dead link. Likewise, what little documentation I could find on it was far from direct.

Comment: Its not totally clear what you want, but `colorRamp` doesn't predefine the number of colours in the palette - it returns colours on a continuum based on input from 0 to 1. If you scale your inputs to (0,1) then colorRamp should work for you.  I think I wrote colourschemes to provide purely functional data-colour mappings but nobody seemed to use it so I let it die...

Comment: With a little hacking, you can create any ramp you want. I recently took the output of `grey(0:127/128)` , which looks like `"#000000" "#020202" "#040404" ...` and edited to get `red_128` which looks like `"#000000" "#020000" "#040000"...` .  Or you could use `rainbow(length(yourdata))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, a colorRamp should work just fine. See this example

```
cr<-colorRamp(c("red","blue"))

x<-1:30
y<-runif(30)

#normalize y to 0-1
ny <- (y-min(y))/diff(range(y))

plot(y~x, col=rgb(cr(ny), maxColorValue=255))
```

That produces

[image]

Comment: That laid it out quite simply. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put fixing up `colourschemes` and putting it on github/CRAN on my todo list.